# How to use SUBSTRING and STR_TO_DATE both in single query?

Tags: mysql

last_date=17/3/2017

SELECT (SUBSTRING  (SELECT STR_TO_DATE( last_date, '%d/%m/%Y' ), 1,4)) FROM table_name

I want month .  like a 03

Comment: is `last_date` a varchar or a date column?

Comment: Why do you need `STR_TO_DATE` (which converts a string to a DATE) in order to extract three characters from a STRING (which you have before you convert it to a date with STR_TO_DATE)? You should actually **read and understand** the code you write or copy/paste before using it.

Comment: What data type is `last_date`? You've shown some sort of value assignment, but what is the actual data type of the column that stores that value (the one used in the CREATE TABLE to define the column)?

Comment: yes ,last_date  datatype is varchar

Answer (score 3):

Your query doesn't make sense because you are converting text to a date and then trying to take the substring of that date.  If you want the month you could try:

```
SELECT
    MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(last_date, '%d/%m/%Y')) AS month
FROM table_name
```

But really you should not be storing your dates as text in the first place.